# Finding $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x} \cdot \int_x^1 \frac{e^{1/t}}{t} \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to find the following :

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x} \cdot \int_x^1 \frac{e^{1/t}}{t} \mathrm{d}t$$

I tried the following :

- $e^{1/t-1/x}/(xt) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(1/t-1/x)^k}{(xt)^k}$ yet I am enable to find an antiderivative of the function : $x \mapsto \frac{(1/t-1/x)^k}{(xt)^k}$...

Answer (score 2):

Apply L'Hopital's Rule. $\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac {\int_x^{1}{e^{1/t} /t dt}} {xe^{1/x}}=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac {-\frac  1 xe^{1/x}} {(1-\frac 1 x)e^{1/x}}=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac 1  {1-x}=1$

Comment: Thank you. There should be an other way to solve this without using l'hôpital Rule since I don't know this theorem.

Comment: @ZingZong this can easily be refomatted to be a definition of derivative application instead of L'Hopital.

Comment: @ZingZong L'Hôpital's Rule is a useful technique, I recommend you to learn it. It is easy to undertand once you know the concept of derivatives. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: @Thinking By product rule the derivative is $(1) e^{1/x} +x e^{1/x} (-\frac 1 {x^{2}})=e^{1/x} (1-\frac 1  x)$.

Comment: There should be a problem with what you are doing since Wolfram alpha is saying the limit is $0$ not $1$ : [Wolfram's reponse](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28Ei%281%29-Ei%28x%29%29*%28e%5E%7B-1%2Fx%7D%2Fx%29+as+x+-%3E+0)

Comment: @Thinking: the integral is $\text{Ei}(1/x)-\text{Ei}(1)$, not what you wrote.